# I am trying to copy a large list to an excel spreadsheet in python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

The list has 10,000,000 random numbers in it, and I can't figure out how to get the code to go to the next row when I reach the 16,384 column limit.

Current code:

```
import csv
import random 
values = []

for i in range(1,10000000):
    
    n = random.randint(0, 1000000)
    values.append(n)
    print(n)

file = open('randresults.csv', 'w')
with file:
    wr = csv.writer(file, dialect = 'excel')
    wr.writerow(values)
file.close()
```

I tried using wr.writerows(values) but it gives me Error: iterable expected, not float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After every 16384 values you should write the values array, reset the values array and write it again on the next loop. you need a counter to count the columns

```
import csv
import random 
values = []

file = open('randresults.csv', 'w')

wr = csv.writer(file, dialect = 'excel')
col_count = 0
for i in range(1,10000000):
    col_count = col_count + 1
    n = random.randint(0, 1000000)
    values.append(n)
    if col_count == 16384:
        wr.writerow(values)
        col_count = 0
        values = []
# write the remaining values, an incomplete row
wr.writerow(values)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, one thing I had to add another wr.writerow outside of the for loop so it would write the remaining values.

Comment: @Spencerbane, you are right with the last `wr.writerow()` after the loop, I had that in mind but forgot to put it on code :(. Answer updated